# Make Header Not-Fixed All Pages

Tags: html, css, header

On all pages my header is fixed to the top of the page. I cannot figure out how to remove that from the theme and make it not-fixed. Please Advise.

http://threadsforheads.net

Comment: If your theme doesn't allow you the option to disable a sticky header then that's just weird, but you could always apply your own custom styles. Some themes also provide a specific location for custom styles in the theme options. But if there are none, then explore some plugins that will allow you to add custom styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

to

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the smart fix. Replacing fixed with absolute definitely takes care of a lot of bugs you would otherwise get by simply taking away the 'fixed' part! Genius, even. -- But even so, I wouldn't recommend it. You see, it's a global classname from bootstrap. It would have to be overwritten in custom css, still, or it would break every time the theme gets an update.

Comment: hey its a start im not here to reprogramm it just give a hint where to start

Comment: @RudiUrbanek This worked well. I will use it as a temporary fix as I search for the correct way with the theme. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have below tag in your HTML,

<
nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top navbar-transparent" role="navigation" 
>

Remove the class name "navbar-fixed-top" from the nav tag.

Comment: You took took quick of a look. Javascript also does stuff to it and it will create lots of graphical bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, any decent wordpress theme I know of has the option to turn that off in the theme's custom settings.

*I would recommend you ask for support from the themebuilder or maybe even just go searching through the options yourself.*

You see, this navigational bar is controlled by a combination of javascript and css. We can't simply say "This will fix it!" because it's actually quite complicated, and we would quite possibly break your theme, possibly breaking other stuff we don't want to break.

*note that changing the files in your theme directly will cause them to reverse your changes on an update*

Comment: I appreciate the reply. Unfortunately there is no quick setting in the theme to do this. It isn't the greatest theme. I used a reply from below as a temporary solution until I get a reply from support.